# Uploading an elaborated proof from a published paper on arxiv

Tags: arxiv

I have elaborated a proof from a paper published on arxiv to make it more intuitive. There is no new innovation in my approach nor does it review the other related proofs for the problem. Is it worthwhile uploading this to arxiv?

I do believe it will add value to the understanding for a newcomer to the field, but it doesn't really add value to anyone who is an expert in the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think that's a great idea.  arXiv is a good place for expository work like this, which may be of value to the scientific community (experts or learners) but isn't novel enough to be published in a journal.